# Slide to right and not left

Tags: swiftui

i am new in SwiftUI and try to slide right , when i click the Button "tray.2" but it doesnt work and slide to left... Please help
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWu76.png)

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct InboxView: View {    
    var folderpath: String
    var name: String
    
    @State var goToFolders = false
   
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            MailListView(folderpath: folderpath, name: name)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersitentDataProvider.dataProvider.persistentContainer.viewContext)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: self.folderButton, trailing: keyManagementButton)
        }
    }
    
    private var keyManagementButton: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: KeyManagementOverview(),
            label: {
                Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3").imageScale(.large)
            })
    }
    
    private var folderButton: some View {
        Button(action:{
         
            goToFolders = true
            
            
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "tray.2").imageScale(.large)
        })
        .background(
            NavigationLink(destination: FolderOverView()
                            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersitentDataProvider.dataProvider.persistentContainer.viewContext), isActive: $goToFolders) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .hidden()
        )
    }
    
}



struct InboxView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        return InboxView(folderpath: "INBOX", name: "INBOX")
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersitentDataProvider.proxyPersistentDataProvider.persistentContainer.viewContext)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example that doesn't rely on a bunch of custom views and types?

Comment: I only write 3 swift classes